# Kafka(0.9.0.0) gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Steps followed:

```
cd /opt/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1  --partitions 1 --topic topic-test

bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic-test
```

**Time of occurance**: The moment You write anything in the producer bash this error starts coming up

**Already Tried**: eleting topics from zookeper bash and removing topic logs in tmp location

```
[2018-10-25 10:03:17,919] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2018-10-25 10:03:18,080] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [topic-test,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2018-10-25 10:03:18,099] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [topic-test,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2018-10-25 10:03:48,864] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ApiKeys.forId(ApiKeys.java:68)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.getRequest(AbstractRequest.java:39)
    at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:79)
    at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$run$11.apply(SocketServer.scala:426)
    at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$run$11.apply(SocketServer.scala:421)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It would be very helpful if someone provides a deep insight for trouble shooting other error like this in the future.

Comment: What is the version of your Kafka brokers and your Kafka clients?

Comment: I am not sure but on googling i was able to find this from my machine kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0.jar and kafka-clients-0.9.0.0.jar

in path /opt/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/libs

Comment: Is it possible to delete some metadata files from my system thereby restoring it to the initial setup? . Because it use to work with its basic Bash producer and consumer .

Comment: Maybe you've hit this bug? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3547

Comment: OK do you have any workaround to restore to previous condition. As i have killed kafka and zookeeper and restarded have the same issue.

Comment: trying to install 0.10.0.0 to fix it

Comment: I **downloaded the latest /kafka_2.11-2.0.0** and followed the steps:
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1  --partitions 1 --topic topic-test
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic-test
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic-test --from-beginning

Things working fine . **Please note --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 has changed in consumer script**

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **downloaded the latest /kafka_2.11-2.0.0** and followed the steps:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties 
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties 
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic topic-test 
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic-test 
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic-test --from-beginning
```

Things working fine. 
**Please note --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 has changed in consumer script**